# Creating a pandas DataFrame with counts of categorical data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, categorical-data

I have a bunch of survey data broken down by number of responses for each choice for each question (multiple-choice questions). I have one of these summaries for each of several different courses, semesters, sections, etc. Unfortunately, all of my data was given to me in PDF printouts and I cannot get the digital data. On the bright side, that means I have free reign to format my data file however I need to so that I can import it into Pandas.

How do I import my data into Pandas, preferably without needing to reproduce it line-by-line (one line for each entry represented by my summary).

## The data

My survey comprises several multiple-choice questions. I have the number of respondents who chose each option for each question. Something like:

```py
Course Number: 100
Semester: Spring
Section: 01

Question 1
----------
Option A: 27
Option B: 30
Option C: 0
Option D: 2

Question 2
----------
Option X: 20
Option Y: 10
```

So essentially I have the `.value_counts()` results if my data was already in Pandas. Note that the questions do not always have the same number of options (categories), and they do not always have the same number of respondents. I will have similar results for multiple course numbers, semesters, and sections.

The categories `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. are just placeholders here to represent the labels for each response category in my actual data.

Also, I have to manually input all of this into something, so I am not worried about reading the specific file format above, it just represents what I have on the actual printouts in front of me.

## The goal

I would like to recreate the response data in Pandas by telling Pandas how many of each response category I have for each question. Basically I want an Excel file or CSV that looks like the response data above, and a Pandas DataFrame that looks like:

```py
Course Number   Semester   Section   Q1   Q2
100             Spring     01        A    X
100             Spring     01        A    X
... (20 identical entries)
100             Spring     01        A    Y
100             Spring     01        A    Y
... (7 of these)
100             Spring     01        B    Y
100             Spring     01        B    Y
100             Spring     01        B    Y
100             Spring     01        B    N/A  (out of Q2 responses)
...
100             Spring     01        D    N/A
100             Spring     01        D    N/A
```

I should note that I am not reproducing the *actual* response data here, because I have no way of knowing that someone who chose option `D` for question 1 didn't also choose option `X` for question 2. I just want the number of each result to show up the same, and for my `df.count_values()` output to basically give me what my summary already says.

## Attempts so far

So far the best I can come up with is actually reproducing each response as its own row in an excel file, and then importing this file and converting to categories:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("filename")
df["Q1"] = df["Q1"].astype("category")
df["Q2"] = df["Q2"].astype("category")
```

There are a couple of problems with this. First, I have thousands of responses, so creating all of those rows is going to take way too long. I would much prefer the compact approach of just recording directly how many of each response I have and then importing that into Pandas.

Second, this becomes a bit awkward when I do not have the same number of responses for every question. At first, to save time on entering every response, I was only putting a value in a column when that value was different than the previous row, and then using `.ffill()` to forward-fill the values in the Pandas DataFrame. The issue with that is that all `NaN` values get filled, so I cannot have different numbers of responses for different questions.

I am not married to the idea of recording the data in Excel first, so if there is an easier way using something else I am all ears.

If there is some other way of looking at this problem that makes more sense than what I am attempting here, I am open to hearing about that as well.

## Edit: kind of working

I switched gears a bit and made an Excel file where each sheet is a single survey summary, the first few columns identify the `Course`, `Semester`, `Section`, `Year`, etc., and then I have a column of possible `Response` categories. The rest of the file comprises a column for each question, and then the number of responses in each row corresponding to the responses that match that question. I then import each sheet and concatenate:

```py
df = [pd.read_excel("filename", sheetname=i, index_col=range(0,7)) for i in range(1,3)]
df = pd.concat(df)
```

This seems to work, but I end up with a really ugly table (lots of NaN's for all of the responses that don't actually correspond to each question). I can kind of get around this for plotting the results for any one question with something like:

```py
df_grouped = df.groupby("Response", sort=False).aggregate(sum)  # group according to response
df_grouped["Q1"][np.isfinite(df_grouped["Q1"])].plot(kind="bar")  # only plot responses that have values
```

I feel like there must be a better way to do this, maybe with multiple indices or some kind of 3D data structure...

Comment: Where'd you get the pdf from, maybe they have it as a csv/better format?

Comment: Sadly no, I asked. I think somebody up the chain might, but I cannot get the actual report data in a format that I can easily use.

Comment: Is it a single file for each course, are there multiple semesters in the same file? Multiple sections?

Comment: The digital file is whatever I want it to be. I have one PDF printout for each section of each semester of each course for three years. Each printout has 29 questions, and each question has between 3 and 11 possible response categories. I have about 50 PDFs to go through and enter into some digital format so that I can bring them into Pandas and do my analysis. Recreating the responses one-by-one is taking too long, so I'd like to just read in the number for each category for each question, broken up by semester, year, etc.

Comment: I think the easiest is to keep them as separate files and do some basic parsing. split by ---- and then for each line get the letter and number :)

Comment: Good idea, but how do I import the number of each response category? I cannot figure out how to do this short of creating a separate row in whatever I import for each response, which is taking way too long. If I can figure out a way to import data in this way, I can build my data file around that, whatever it ends up being.

Answer (score 0):

One hacky way to get the information out is to first split by ----- and then use regex.

For each course so something like the following:

```
In [11]: s
Out[11]: 'Semester: Spring\nSection: 01\nQuestion 1\n----------\nOption A: 27\nOption B: 30\nOption C: 0\nOption D: 2\n\nQuestion 2\n----------\nOption A: 20\nOption B: 10'

In [12]: blocks = s.split("----------")
```

Parse out the information from the first block, use regex or just split:

```
In [13]: semester = re.match("Semester: (.*)", blocks[0]).groups()[0]

In [14]: semester
Out[14]: 'Spring'
```

To parse the option info from each block:

```
def parse_block(lines):
    d = {}
    for line in lines:
        m = re.match("Option ([^:]+): (\d+)", line)
        if m:
            d[m.groups()[0]] = int(m.groups()[1])
    return d

In [21]: [parse_block(x.splitlines()) for x in blocks[1:]]
Out[21]: [{'A': 27, 'B': 30, 'C': 0, 'D': 2}, {'A': 20, 'B': 10}]
```

You can similarly pull out the question number (if you don't know they're sequential):

```
In [22]: questions = [int(re.match(".*Question (\d+)", x, re.DOTALL).groups()[0]) for x in blocks[:-1]]

In [23]: questions
Out[23]: [1, 2]
```

and zip these together:

```
In [31]: dict(zip(questions, ds))
Out[31]: {1: {'A': 27, 'B': 30, 'C': 0, 'D': 2}, 2: {'A': 20, 'B': 10}}

In [32]: pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(questions, ds)))
Out[32]:
    1   2
A  27  20
B  30  10
C   0 NaN
D   2 NaN
```

*I'd put these in another dict of (course, semester, section) -> DataFrame and then concat and work out where to go from the big MultiIndex dataFrame...*

Comment: Cool, but I want my `df.value_counts()` to output basically what your DataFrame is showing. So I want to reproduce each response in my DataFrame by giving Pandas the number of responses of each category for each question.

Comment: @Engineero I don't think you should do that.

Comment: @Engineero that said, that aspect could make a great question by itself. ("How to de-aggregate a pandas DataFrame" ?)

Comment: Haha, OK, well then I am not sure how I should organize my DataFrame. It looks like I get into trouble if I want to, for instance, be able to only look at responses to question 1 from two specific semesters of a certain year for one class.

Comment: @Engineero it's all about the MultiIndex http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html